# OrientDB with spring mvc configuration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, orientdb, spring-security-oauth2, orientdb2.2

Please suggest me how can i configure the orientdb with spring mvc.

```
<bean id="databaseFactory" class="org.ops4j.orient.spring.tx.OrientObjectDatabaseFactory"
    p:url="remote:localhost/MyDB" p:username="userName" p:password="pwd" />

<bean id="orTransactionManager" class="org.ops4j.orient.spring.tx.OrientTransactionManager"
    p:databaseManager-ref="databaseFactory" />
```

I have added above code into my mvc-dispacher-servlet.xml file

and i have added dependencies also in to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.ops4j.orient</groupId>
            <artifactId>orient-spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
            <artifactId>orientdb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
            <artifactId>orientdb-graphdb</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.13</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
        <artifactId>orientdb-enterprise</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0-beta</version>
    </dependency>
```

My OrientDb server is 2.2.13 version which is latest.
help me in configuring it.if possible suggest a sample project URL also.

Thank You

Comment: See: https://github.com/orientechnologies/spring-data-orientdb and https://github.com/noskovd/spring-data-orient

Comment: I got it working with following

Comment: <bean id="orientDatabaseFactory" class="org.ops4j.orient.spring.tx.OrientObjectDatabaseFactory">
  <property name="url" value="${database.orientdb.url}" />
  <property name="username" value="${database.orientdb.username}" />
  <property name="password" value="${database.orientdb.password}" />
 </bean>

Comment: remove the orient-enterprise dependency. Bear in mind to use only one version for every dependency on orientdb